# Converting Document object to Byte[]

Tags: java, xml, dom, arrays

I am init Document object like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
```

After that I am building an XML file by inserting data to the doc object.

Finally I am writing the contents to a file on my computer.

My question is how to write the contents of doc in to a `byte[]`?*

This is how i write the content to the XML file:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("changeOut.xml"));
// Output to console for testing
// StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pass *OutputStream* instead of *File* to the `StreamResult` constructor.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 StreamResult result=new StreamResult(bos);
 transformer.transform(source, result);
 byte []array=bos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

This work for me:

```
public byte[] documentToByte(Document document)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.outputDOM(document, baos, true);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Do you have dependency details of org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.outputDOM ? I got only node support class file

Answer (score 2):

Put a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) where you have the File and you should be good.